# If the list has a property that is again a list, get its first value

Tags: c#, linq, list, datatable

I have a `List` of `Objects` (integer, string, date, etc) and I was trying to convert this list into a `DataTable`. It worked fine until I realized that my objects in the list can actually be `List`s themselves. And in this case I would like to get their first value, otherwise I will get meaningless data in my `DataTable`.

So I need a LINQ query to go through a generic list and if the object is not a List return its value, but if it is return its first value. So eventually I get a `List` again except that this time all its members have a value.

Comment: Could you show your code attempt?

Answer (score 1):

To handle arbitrary deep nesting, you'll need a little recursive method that checks if an object is a list:

```
object GetValue(object obj)
{
    var list = obj as IList;
    if (list != null)
        return GetValue(list[0]);
    return obj;
}
```

Then filtering the data is as easy as this:

```
var data = new List<object>
{
    1, "Foo",
    new List<object>{ new List<object>{ 2, 3, 4 }, "Bar" },
    5, 6
};

var filtered = data.Select(GetValue).ToList();
```

If you're sure that the lists inside lists can't contain lists themself, you could also do

```
var filtered = data.Select(obj => obj is IList ? ((IList)obj)[0] : obj).ToList();
```

but using that little helper method is clearer IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SelectMany()

```
    //Create lists of strings
    var a = new List<string> { "A", "B" };
    var b = new List<string> { "C", "D" };
    var c = new List<string> { "E", "F" };

    //Create a list containing all the lists
    var abc = new List<List<string>> { a, b, c };

    //Get the values
    var strings = abc.
        SelectMany(o => o).
        ToList();
```

Comment: OP has a `List<object>`, not a `List<List<string>>`. `SelectMany` will not work here. `strings` would be `A, B, C, D, E, F`, whereas OP would want `A, C, E`.